# Disabling third party SDK for a specific build

Tags: unity-game-engine

I've been using my own custom build scripts for a long time to help me run local test builds faster without setting every option.
I've come to the point where I don't know how to fix the problem automatically, but I know what steps to take to fix it manually.

> Simplified types of builds:
>
> 1) Test Build - I don't want SDK here.
>
> 2) Release Build - Full Build with all components

When I'm using custom build script and run a release build and then a test build, it seems that SDK is not used in the build (by log message and pre-processor derivatives), but it is included (by the build time). This is the case I want to fix.

Manually, after doing any script changes the "compiling scripts" dialog appears and the next build is done correctly.

I was trying to use `AssetDatabase.Refresh();`, but it doesn't help.

The method I'm using for disabling SDK in test build:

```
PluginImporter sdk = AssetImporter.GetAtPath("Assets/sdk/Plugins/sdk.dll") as PluginImporter;
sdk.SetCompatibleWithPlatform(BuildTarget.WebGL, false);
```

as well as setting correct pre-processor derivative.